# How do you parse a string with newlines into lists in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string output that I would like to break into separate lists between any occurrence of `"Map"`.

```
string =  "Map \n
North Prong\n
Nonspecific+\n
W\n
A\n
20\n
A\n
20\n
A\n
20\n
A\n
20\n
Map\n
South Prong\n
Nonspecific+\n
W\n
A\n
20\n
A\n
20\n
A\n
20\n
A\n
20\n
Map\n
Trailway Hike-in\n
Nonspecific+\n
W\n
A\n
50\n
A\n
50\n
A\n
50\n
A\n
50\n
Map\n
HF001\n
Honey Flat\n
R\n
R\n
R\n
R\n
R\n
Map\n
HF003\n
Honey Flat\n
R\n
A\n
R\n
R\n
R\n
Map\n
HF004\n
Honey Flat\n
R\n
R\n
R\n
R\n
R\n"
```

I need this broken down into separate list elements.

Desired Output:

```
[['North Prong', 'Nonspecific+', 'W', 'A', '20', 'A', '20', 'A', '20',
'A', '20'],['South Prong', 'Nonspecific+', 'W', 'A', '20', 'A', '20',
'A', '20', 'A', '20'],['Trailway Hike-in', 'Nonspecific+', 'W', 'A',
'50', 'A', '50', 'A', '50', 'A', '50'],['HF001', 'Honey Flat', 'R',
'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'],['HF003', 'Honey Flat', 'R', 'A', 'R', 'R',
'R'],['HF004', 'Honey Flat', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R']]
```

Comment: Simply use `split` function on the string: `string.split("\n")`. You can leave split's arguments blank.

Comment: Using split on \n creates one large list of elements and does not break it down into multiple lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cue where to split into sublists seems to be `Map`. So you can split on `Map` first, then split the sublists at '\n'. You also need to skip the first empty element when splitting at `Map` (hence the `[1:]`) and get rid of leading and trailing whitespace using `strip`.

```py
[[e.strip() for e in d.strip().split('\n')] for d in string.split('Map')[1:]]
```

Comment: Great answer. Just a little note, it would be best if you could use the same variable name as the one OP has used. Beside that, a great answer. +1.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani thank you! I did miss that, meant to suggest using something else as variable name, but then again, `string` is not a builtin per se, so I guess it can stay that way.

Comment: Completely agree with you. `string` usually is a built-in function/variable in other programming languages. But, as you mentioned, it wouldn't harm your answer to leave the variables' names as OP wanted, I guess.